# Grouping nodes with same value from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I am new in Xslt/Xml.

I have XML like that:

```
<entry>
 <attribute1>A</attribute1>
 <attribute2>B</attribute2>
</entry>
<entry>
 <attribute1>A</attribute1>
 <attribute2>B</attribute2>
</entry>
<entry>
 <attribute1>C</attribute1>
 <attribute2>D</attribute2>
</entry>
<entry>
 <attribute1>E</attribute1>
 <attribute2>F</attribute2>
</entry>
...
```

I need table output:

A

```
Attribute1 Attribute2 Qty
   A           B       2
   C           D       1
   E           F       1
```

I need your help, I have no idea how to count unique entries and display it as one in table.

I am using XSLT version 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I. Simple XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kEntryByChildren" match="entry" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match=
 "entry[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('kEntryByChildren', .)[1]))]"/>

 <xsl:template match="entry">
  <tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('kEntryByChildren', .))"/></td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="entry/*">
   <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <table>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML** (the fragment is wrapped ito a single top element to obtain a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <entry>
        <attribute1>A</attribute1>
        <attribute2>B</attribute2>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <attribute1>A</attribute1>
        <attribute2>B</attribute2>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <attribute1>C</attribute1>
        <attribute2>D</attribute2>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <attribute1>E</attribute1>
        <attribute2>F</attribute2>
    </entry>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**When applied on this tricky XML document** (if we used simple concatenation of the children's values, we would incorrectly conclude that the first three `entry` elements are "same"):

```
<t>
    <entry>
        <attribute1>AB</attribute1>
        <attribute2>C</attribute2>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <attribute1>A</attribute1>
        <attribute2>BC</attribute2>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <attribute1>A</attribute1>
        <attribute2>BC</attribute2>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <attribute1>C</attribute1>
        <attribute2>D</attribute2>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <attribute1>E</attribute1>
        <attribute2>F</attribute2>
    </entry>
</t>
```

**the correct result is produced:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>AB</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>BC</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

**Do note**:

1. This solution doesn't depend on the names and number of children of an `entry` element, and thus can be applied if there are more than two children, or varying number of children with unknown beforehand names.
2. **Here we assume that** the concatenation of all children's string values is the same only when the same children have the same values.

---

**II. Full XSLT 1.0 solution**:

In case the assumption 2. above cannot be guaranteed, this is one possible XSLT 1.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="entry">
  <xsl:variable name="vChildrenFp">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '+')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vPrecedingSame">
    <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::entry">
     <xsl:variable name="vthisFP">
       <xsl:for-each select="*">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '+')"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:if test="$vthisFP = $vChildrenFp">1</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:if test="not(string($vPrecedingSame))">
      <xsl:variable name="vFollowingSame">
        <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::entry">
         <xsl:variable name="vthisFP">
           <xsl:for-each select="*">
             <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '+')"/>
           </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:variable>

         <xsl:if test="$vthisFP = $vChildrenFp">1</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>

      <tr>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="string-length($vFollowingSame)+1"/></td>
      </tr>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="entry/*">
   <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <table>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**:

1. For each `entry` element we generate a "fingerprint" (FP) of its children and process this `entry` element if none of its preceding sibling `entry` element has the same children's fingerprint.
2. The count of "same" `entry` elements is done in a similar way -- for any following sibling `entry` element with the same children's FP value, we output a single character ('1'). The total count is the string-length of the so generated string (of "1"s) plus 1.

---

**III. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="pExoticString" select="'+'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <table>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="my:fingerprint(.)">
       <tr>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/></td>
       </tr>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
   </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="entry/*">
   <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:fingerprint" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="pParent" as="element()"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="string-join($pParent/*, $pExoticString)"/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This simple solution easily handles the complicated case. When applied on the last XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
            <td>AB</td>
            <td>C</td>
         <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>BC</td>
         <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
         <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
         <td>1</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of **[`xsl:for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#xsl-for-each-group)**, **[`xsl:function`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-function)**, **[`current-group()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#function-current-group)** and **[`string-join()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join)**.

Answer (score 4):

Take this short, just as starting point:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:key name="keys" match="entry" use="concat(attribute1,'|',attribute2)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/test">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry[
          generate-id() 
          = generate-id(key('keys',concat(attribute1,'|',attribute2))[1])]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
            attribute1,' ', 
            attribute2,' ',
            count(key('keys',concat(attribute1,'|',attribute2))),'&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you are new to XSLT, to understand this transformation you'll need to read about:

- xslt output methods
- xsl:key element
- Meunchian grouping
- xpath concat and count function
- xpath | union